# update array localstorage with vanilla

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I´m trying to delete element from array stored in localstorage, i´m working with javascript vanilla in component vuejs 3. This it´s my `array`.

```
["96", "281", "287", "415", "650", "661", "378", "295"]
```

when i clicked in my trash:

[image]

I have a function to delete this row:

```
const removeItem = (event) => {
        let itemId = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].id;
        console.log(itemId)

        // save ids in LocalStorage to in next steps send to controller
        // first delete all content from LocalStorage
        const existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items_ids"));
        existingEntries.splice(itemId, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("items_ids", JSON.stringify(existingEntries))

        addItemCart.value = addItemCart.value.filter(item => item.id != itemId);
    }
```

I need update my `array` in `localstore`. with this code, not delete index and not updated my data.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

update:

with accepted response i can to do that my code run and it´s very pretty:

```
const removeItem = (event) => {
        let itemId = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].id;

        // save ids in LocalStorage to in next steps send to controller
        // first delete all content from LocalStorage
        addItemCart.value = addItemCart.value.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId);
        let newArrayIds = []
        addItemCart.value.forEach(element => {
            newArrayIds.push(element.id)
        });
        localStorage.setItem("items_ids", JSON.stringify(newArrayIds));
    }
```

with this code, update my table and my localstorage ok.

Comment: `javascript vanilla` as opposed to what other flavour? `existingEntries.splice(itemId, 1);` does `itemId` refer to the index position of an item? no ... you want to use `.filter.(v => v!=itemId)`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes better strawberry flavor.... i want delete element, mayby i´m confusing with position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here, is Vue is not watching your localStorage so it has no idea when to update.
If you need to use your localStorage, you should let Vue know whether it has changed or not. Something like..

```js
...
  data() {
    return {
      yourList: []
    }
  }
...
 methods: {
    removeItem (clickedId) {
      this.yourList = this.yourList.filter((item) => item.id !== clickedId);
      localStorage.setItem("items_ids", JSON.stringify(this.yourList));
    }
  },
```

So in this code we're not controlling data from localStroage. We control reactivity data which is `yourList` and just keep updating localStorage manually

Comment: your code it´s my solution, thank you very much. In my question, i updated  it to add my definitive code to do i need.